# mysqldump does not want import data inside mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I try to import a large database (18mmo) inside mysql but it does'nt want to do that

my command :

```
mysqldump -u root -p c1_forum > data-dump.sql
```

tk

Comment: *doesn't want to do that* isn't a valid error message...

Comment: @BenM there is no error, it come back to the prompt. Don't understand why it does'nt want to import the db

Comment: That's an observation, which while important, is also not a diagnostic we can help you with. There's way too many reasons why that might happen. The way to narrow that down is to get an error, *any* error, so we have something to start with.

Comment: The mysqldump tool doesn't do import. It only *outputs* a dump file. You need to use the [mysql client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html) to read the dump file and run the SQL statements to import it.